# Implementation of a latch

Tags: c++, multithreading, reinventing-the-wheel, concurrency, atomic

As an exercise to learn more about multi-threading and atomic operations work in C++, I decided to implement a *latch* class in C++11 loosely based off of [`std::latch`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/latch) class from C++20 and would like to know whether this implementation is flawed in any sort of way or form and how I could improve upon it:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>

class latch {
    std::atomic<std::ptrdiff_t> counter_;
    mutable std::mutex mut_;

public:
    explicit latch(std::ptrdiff_t const def = 1) : counter_(def) {}

    void count_down(std::ptrdiff_t const n = 1) {
        counter_ -= n;
    }

    void wait() const {
        if (!counter_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) return;
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mut_);
        while (counter_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed));
    }

    bool try_wait() const noexcept {
        return !counter_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    }

    void arrive_and_wait(std::ptrdiff_t const n = 1) {
        count_down(n);
        wait();
    }
};
```

I also tried to [test it out](https://godbolt.org/z/4s7TGW1h6) and it *appears* to work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing missing that's present in `std::latch` is the `max` constant.  We can easily add that:

```
static constexpr std::ptrdiff_t max() noexcept
{
    return std::numeric_limits<std::ptrdiff_t>::max();
}
```

I think that `wait()` is flawed: the first thread to get here (taking the mutex) will busy-loop (`while`).  Really, we should wait on a condition variable so that we're not consuming resources while the other threads are still progressing.

Comment: Taking what you said into consideration, would [this](https://godbolt.org/z/bK8oq8oaE) be correct way to do it then?

Comment: I _think_ so - perhaps worth posting that as a follow-on question - link back to this one to help give context if you like.

Comment: `std::lock_guard(mut_);` must be added above line 15.