# C++11 revised `std::latch` implementation

Tags: c++, multithreading, reinventing-the-wheel, concurrency, atomic

This question follows up on [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/269342/implementation-of-a-latch).

After turning the `while`-loop into a *conditional wait* using `std::condition_variable`, I would like to know if there are *still* any flaws/problems with this code which implements the [`std::latch` class from C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/latch) in C++11:

```cpp
#include <condition_variable>
#include <cstdint>
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>

class latch {
    std::atomic<std::ptrdiff_t> counter_;
    mutable std::condition_variable cv_;
    mutable std::mutex mut_;

public:
    explicit latch(std::ptrdiff_t const def = 1) : counter_(def) {}

    void count_down(std::ptrdiff_t const n = 1) {
        counter_ -= n;
        cv_.notify_all();
    }

    void wait() const {
        if (counter_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == 0) return;
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mut_);
        cv_.wait(lock, [=] { return counter_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == 0; });
    }

    bool try_wait() const noexcept {
        return counter_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == 0;
    }

    void arrive_and_wait(std::ptrdiff_t const n = 1) {
        count_down(n);
        wait();
    }

    static constexpr std::ptrdiff_t max() noexcept {
        return std::numeric_limits<std::ptrdiff_t>::max();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Some minor nitpicks about the constructor:

- It should be `constexpr`.
- It shouldn't have a default argument.
- We should check that the argument is valid (not negative, and not greater than `max()`). The standard says it's undefined behavior otherwise, so we don't technically have to, but it's nicer to `assert` than to silently carry on.

---

Another thing:

```
    counter_ -= n;
    cv_.notify_all();
```

`operator-=()` here is doing `counter.fetch_sub(n, std::memory_order_seq_cst);`.

While this memory order will be safe, I'm not sure it's necessary. I suspect you could get away with `std::memory_order_release` (note: I'm not very familiar with `atomic<>`s, so you might want a second opinion).

In any case, using an explicit `fetch_sub` call is clearer, and also allows us to add an assertion that the previous value of `counter` was greater than or equal to `n`.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest offender here in terms of performance here is

```
void count_down(std::ptrdiff_t const n = 1) {
    counter_ -= n;
    cv_.notify_all();
}
```

While the `std::memory_order_seq_cst` is surely too strong here, as `std::memory_order_release` should be sufficient, this is but a minor issue compared to the `cv_.notify_all()` that you trigger all the time completely unnecessarily. Think what it does: it awakens all the threads that wait for counter to reach 0 only finding out that the variable is not zero. Awakening of each thread costs thousands of cycles and you do it on all waiting thread on each count down. Then putting it to sleep also costs thousands of cycles. It is a total waste.

Instead, you should trigger the `notify_all()` only when the counter reached `0`.

Next: memory order bugs with `wait()` and `try_wait()`. Think what happens when counter reached `0`. You've only triggered relaxed memory order instructions. It means that whatever changes occurred on other threads on other variables they aren't necessarily synchronized with the currently running thread. You ought to trigger memory order acquire synchronization with the atomic variable when that happens.
Also make sure that it is triggered on the atomic variable regardless of the fact that mutex applies memory synchronization routines. They aren't necessarily the same routines or matching routines considering that you try to utilize efficiency of the `std::atomic` for lightweight operations. Mixing atomics with mutex is always problematic.

`arrive_and_wait` routine. You can mildly optimize it for the case when the counter reaches zero on the current thread. Just make sure you apply proper memory synchronization routines - both release and acquire on the atomic.

It would be much simpler and straightforward if you were to implement all of this with mutex and non-atomic variable it guards. But it would cause `count_down` and `try_wait` to be less efficient due to unnecessary calls to acquire atomic memory instructions.